# Android Developing - Slow Internet Connection via 3G

Tags: android, http, connection, client

I'm developing a Client/Server Application with Android/Rails and Communication via REST Json

When I'm testing my App via Emulator, all works fine.
Also when I deploy the app on my phone with **WIFI on** it works and the speed is ok.

But when I disconnect from WIFI and use the 3G connection, the phone becomes incredible Slow and it takes Minutes du get one JSON Response from the Server.

I'ved debug a little bit and the Problem seems to be the HTTPClient, which execute Method takes ulta long.

**Other Apps with Network Access are working perfectly.**

Any suggestions what to do?

```
HTC Magic 
Android 1.6
```

My Http Connection Code:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet("URL");
        try {
            client.execute(get);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Can you connect to the same server from a different app, maybe the browser?  I've noticed an unfortunate trend lately for connections from one ISP or another to a particular web site to be outrageously slow for a while, even while other sites and other ISPs are fine.

Comment: Hey, that is a hint, with my broweser i cant access the webpage in normal speed.

Comment: Im Using DynDns to map an url to my local Server. Port is 3000, so se url is something.dyndns.org:3000/getPersons.json for example. Can this be the issue? Wenn my Phone is connected with WIFI, it perhaps take my router to access it. ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: Some Problems with the Port. I changed my Server Port from 3000 to 80 and it works just fine. Thanks for the Comment, that was the great Hint :). 
Thanks to  Chris Stratton

Answer (score -1):

Move to an area with better mobile data coverage?

Comment: Hehe, ive forgotten to say that other apps work perfect (Browser, Yelp,...) so the Problem is not the Connection itself but my App.

Comment: Its edited in the first post. Very Basic, ni much place for Mistakes but its slow as hell :( Do i need some other permissions than INTERNET?